# How to run TypeScript program on Windows?

Tags: javascript, typescript

If we write a Typescript program then how should we run it on Windows?

We already know how to run **Javascript** (`.js`) from a command line on Windows:

```
C:\Users\Harikesh>cscript MyScriptFile.js
```

What is the equivalent for **TypeScript** (`.ts`) files?

Comment: how do you run javascript on windows platform?

Comment: Using `NodeJS` and [TypeScript Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript).

Comment: For general guidance, TypeScript's [Quick Start](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Tutorial) guide describes the options for installing TypeScript and how to use it to execute a `.ts` script that you've written. Is there a specific part of that you're having issues with?

Comment: @qxg `>cscript example.js`

Answer (score 6):

You can compile the Typescript down to Javascript, and then run it from a command line with Node.js, or in a web browser:

1) [Download](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and install Node.js.

2) Open a Windows command prompt and run:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

3) Navigate to the directory where your typescript file is in, and type:

```
tsc yourtypescriptfile.ts
```

4a) Run the resulting JavaScript file with Node.js:

```
node yourtypescriptfile.js
```

-or-

4b) Make an HTML file (in the same directory) that includes **yourtypescriptfile**.js using `<source></source>` tags:

```
<script src="yourtypescriptfile.js"></script>
```

5) Open your HTML file in a web browser.

Help from:
http://javascript.info/tutorial/adding-script-html

Comment: or simply use `node yourtypescriptfile.js` from command line.

Comment: or simply use `cscript yourtypescriptfile.js` from command line.

Answer (score 0):

> If we write a typescript program then how should we run it on window platform?

Using NodeJS : https://nodejs.org/en/

Same as JavaScript to be exact.

Comment: you mean by npm of typescript ?

Comment: No, I mean compile the `.ts` file to `.js` file and then run it as nodejs script.

Comment: You run a JavaScript program from the command prompt: `>cscript example.js`. No Node needed.